# trying to hide div with content on javascript call

Tags: javascript, css, html, show-hide

I Have been trying to use this http://www.gloucesterwebdesign.com/showhidecontent/

but instead of hitting a link I want some JavaScript to call this function

like

```
    if(input == true){
      toggleLayer('id');
    }
    else if(input == false){
      toggleLayer('id2');
    }
```

the script call the toogleLayer function, but nothing happens, and curse
the input value is place within a other script there runs at page load up. I'm been wondering if this is the problem. anyone who like to comment on this?

-- Update --
So i was ask for more of the code,
http://pastebin.com/UD3tjz1s

- The value in the localStorage is set on a other page, so you only get this page after that. this is only to show what kind of data im using

im a bit of a javaScript noob, so hope it's not to hard to read

Comment: FYI: You don't need `else if` part unless you have any other values to compare except `false`! here `else` is enough.

Comment: As a sidenote, you can also do `toggleLayer(input?'id':'id2')`

Comment: @DhavalMarthak True, but got more values to compare. this was just something i chopped out

Comment: @adeneo thx, didn't see that, but that ain't whats gonna make it work i'm afraid,

Comment: put more of your code, where is your script called? And did you have any errors in the console log/screen?

Comment: It can depend on so many things -- like your script being called before the variable input is declared etc... I also don't get why, instead of calling this function described above, you don't just directly call the toggleLayer for the right layer as you don't use any specific parameters anyway... And the resource you are using is incredibly old.

Comment: @roel http://pastebin.com/B84fB443 here is a sample of what im doing, it work when i press the link, but not when i call it from the script.

Comment: @somethinghere i don't get what you mean, the resource are incredibly old? it's my code or the homepage i been using?

Comment: "Note: older browsers will 'ignore' a div tag" -- I can't even _find_ older browser that don't support the div tag. But apart from that, in your PasteBin check line 30 - You are not actually setting it like you are doing in the if statements below that, you are ALWAYS setting it to none. Since getElementById is supported by ALL browsers, this gets executed every time.  `style2.display = style2.display ?  "none" : "block";` should work, I think.

Comment: @somethinghere Sry forgot to change a little css code. this should be up-to-date. http://pastebin.com/UD3tjz1s and i thought that my css would prevent that? anyway, it didn't work

Comment: @DaCh Setting it to 'none' in JS will hide it nonetheless. Unless you unset it (I think thats done by setting it to '' here), its not going to work. You could try the following line to test this theory on line 30:  `style2.display = style2.display != "none" ? "none" : "block";`, that way everything is done in JS.

Comment: @somethinghere Cool, i gonna try that.

Comment: @somethinghere Sad to say, either im stupid(highly possible), or it's not working. thanks for your time anyway :)

Comment: @DaCh Check my reply. Its awfully simple to do, the problem is that the old resource you are using makes things highly complex for no benefit (supporting layers is not necessary as ALL browsers have support for the getElementByID today).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did a quick test and this will do it. Just replace your current function iwht this, it;s a lot cleaner and simpler. Also, document.getElementById(id) is supported in every current browser and goes back to IE6, so unless you want netscape support you don't; need all the extra code your resource provided.

```
function toggleLayer(id){
    // get the element (this is supported in all modern browsers)
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    // set the style display of this element to none if its set to be
    // anything else than none, otherwise set it to block
        element.style.display = element.style.display != "none"
            ? "none"
            : "block";
 }
```

I tested this and it worked.

### Edit - [different thing!]

Okay, sorry I sort of misunderstood but I found a way to fix it. Heres what it comes down to: Because your javascript code is above your DIV elements, it gets executed BEFORE the DIV elements are created by the page. So javascript will look for the elements, and it will return undefined because, well, they aren't defined yet. SO you will have to either move your script to just before the ending  tag, or add the following to the code (please not I also added an interval to see your function working):

```
window.onload = function(){
        setInterval(setSize,1000);
        // the rest of your functions here - the above interval is so you can see it toggling
}
// function toggleLater(){...} here
```

You might also want to move ToggleLayer OUTSIDE of the window.onload function, as you can't trigger it from the page otherwise (again, the function is now defined INSIDE window.onload and outside of the scope for DIV elements...).

Comment: Thanks a bunch!
So if i take my code an replace the toggleLayer with yours it should work?

Comment: I just tested exactly that and it does.

Comment: Could you be so kind to post it somewhere? curse when i try it is stil only work when i use the link,